# Does the iPhone's NFC have an open interface for developers to use?

Tags: ios, nfc

I searched for a long time, are the 2014 article that there is no open interface for developers to use. And did not find the official description of the document, so consult you have no information in this area?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The iOS SDK provides no direct access to the NFC radio. It can only be used for Apple Pay.

Comment: OK，thank you。have you get the official description of the document about NFC？

Comment: There is no official documentation (that I have found) that specifically says the SDK does **not** provide access. However, there have been multiple news stories claiming that Apple confirmed there is no developer access to NFC for security reasons, there are no documented APIs for accessing the NFC (except via Apple Pay), and I have never seen any real information about accessing the NFC even via jailbreak.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 11 iPhone 7 and 7+ you can detect NFC tags.

- [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corenfc)
- [Code example](https://github.com/hansemannn/iOS11-NFC-Example)